# Read line continuously, with modifications and deletions?

Tags: shell, fish

I'd like to write a script that when invoked responds with a prompt, and at that prompt the entered line is read continuously, without the user having to press enter.

```
$ myscript
>
```

I could almost do this by looping `read -n1` and concatenating the results, but I don't know how to then handle deletes, or cursor movements and inserting characters earlier in the line.

As far as I can tell this functionality isn't built in to `read` implementations, but is there a convenient way to do it?

I'm adding the [fish](/questions/tagged/fish) tag, as I'd be (more than) happy with a fish-specific solution if there isn't a POSIX one.

---

Ideally I would receive the state of the line on stdin, line by line as it happens.

e.g. if the user types `Hi, my name is Chale<D><D>rles` my input would be:

```sh
H
Hi
Hi,
[...]
Hi, my name is Chal
Hi, my name is Chale
Hi, my name is Chal
Hi, my name is Cha
Hi, my name is Char
Hi, my name is Charl
Hi, my name is Charle
Hi, my name is Charles
```

Comment: I'd almost suggest the need for deletion/editing to be described in the question itself; it's a very substantial complicating factor. (What would you expect it to look like to your script when a user is editing a character you already read earlier? That is, what kind of programmatic interface would you want to see to pass in updates, in an ideal world without thinking about feasibility?)

Comment: (err, "in the *question title* itself")

Comment: ...if you look at `libedit` or `readline` (libraries that actually do the work of reading character-by-character and providing an editing interface), they're very substantial software projects, and written in a much lower-level / heavier-duty language than anything natively shell-like. Even higher-level languages' CLI libraries typically use one of those to allow line editing and then read in entire lines post-editing, because doing anything else (especially doing other things portably, with interactive/history/other facilities users expect, &c) is a very substantial amount of work.

Comment: "what kind of programmatic interface" - I was imagining line by line on stdin, I'll update the post with an example.

Comment: Assuming the license isn't incompatible with your needs, I'd use a language with a tight binding to the readline library so you can access the contents of `rl_line_buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in fish, ksh, or any other shell I'm familiar with. In ksh you might be tempted to use the KEYBD trap. The problem is that trap is invoked before the character is acted on (e.g., inserted into the buffer). That is so the KEYBD trap can modify the character. So your function is always one character behind what was typed. You'll need to write a program in C (or a similar language) that uses the readline library (or reinvent that wheel yourself).